# Add actual date to a csv output file name

Tags: r, csv, date

I am exporting data frame from R to a csv file. I'm using the statement

```
write.csv(df, file = "df_2019-12-23.csv", row.names =FALSE)
```

The file name contains the actual date (2019-12-23) but I would like to add this information by a command (and not manually as in my example).

Thank you.

Comment: From where do you get the date ?

Comment: Do you only have one per day? i.e. something like `paste0('df_', Sys.Date(), '.csv')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Sys.Date()` to get the current day's date, i.e.

```
paste0('df_', Sys.Date(), '.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R to write out csv that's name is the name
of the dataframe concatenated with today's date (on your systems timezone), in the current working directory:

```
write.csv(df,
          file = paste0(file.path(
            getwd(), gsub("[[:punct:]]|\\s+", "_",
                          paste0(deparse(substitute(
                            df
                          )), "_",
                          Sys.Date())), ".csv"
          )), row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sotos is correct, however for a more beginner approach i would go with:

```
CurrentDate <- Sys.Date()
write.csv(data, paste0("datafilename",CurrentDate,".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```